# Using RegSetKeySecurity to avoid registry redirection

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, registry, advapi32

In order to avoid registry redirection to Wow64 keys, how to translate the following code that uses `Microsoft.Win32` APIs

```
public void SetKeyAccessControl(
            RegistryKey rootKey, string subKeyName, string identity, 
            RegistryRights rights, InheritanceFlags inheritanceFlags,
            PropagationFlags propagationFlags, AccessControlType accessType)
{
   using (RegistryKey regKey = rootKey.OpenSubKey(subKeyName, true))
   {
       RegistrySecurity acl = new RegistrySecurity();
       RegistryAccessRule rule = new RegistryAccessRule(identity, rights, inheritanceFlags, propagationFlags, accessType);
       acl.AddAccessRule(rule);

       regKey.SetAccessControl(acl);
   }            
}
```

into using advapi32 RegSetKeySecurity API

```
[DllImport(@"advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "RegSetKeySecurity", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern int RegSetKeySecurity(IntPtr handle, uint securityInformation, IntPtr pSecurityDescriptor);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another native method needs to be involved and given an SDDL, the following code sets ACLs on the right registry key:

```
[DllImport("Advapi32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi, SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
internal static extern bool ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor(string stringSecurityDescriptor, int stringSDRevision, out IntPtr ppSecurityDescriptor, ref int securityDescriptorSize);

string sddl = "...";
IntPtr secDescriptor = IntPtr.Zero;
int size = 0;
ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor
   (
      sddl,
      1,                              // revision 1
      out secDescriptor,
      ref size
   );

// get handle with RegOpenKeyEx

RegSetKeySecurity
(
     handle,
     0x00000004,                      // DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION
     secDescriptor
);
```

Answer (score 3):

To avoid Registry redirection, you could do something like this...

```
SafeRegistryHandle handle = rootKey.Handle;

RegistryKey rootKey32 = RegistryKey.FromHandle(handle, RegistryView.Registry32);

RegistryKey rootKey64 = RegistryKey.FromHandle(handle, RegistryView.Registry64);
```

You can then use rootKey32 or rootKey64 to open a subkey and you'll get the subkey of the view requested.

At least it works in the few test cases I've tried.  And, according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd411625.aspx) for FromHandle...

> The view parameter for this method is used in subsequent operations,
>   such as opening subkeys

Comment: If you're working with 2.0 perhaps it would be easier to use the Common Language Runtime support in C++ to implement your SetKeyAccessControl function.  That way you could use native C++ to call RegOpenKeyEx supplying the [appropriate flag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384129(v=VS.85).aspx) in the `samDesired` parameter.