# Programmatically assign the permission to a registry subkey

Tags: c#, .net, permissions, registry

Here is how we `manually` assign the permissions to a registry key:

**To assign permissions to a registry key**

- Open Registry Editor. Click the key to which you want to assign permissions.
- On the Edit menu, click Permissions.
- Assign an access level to the selected key as follows:
- To grant the user permission to read the key contents, but not save
  any changes made to the file, under Permissions for name, for **Read**,
  select the Allow check box.
- To grant the user permission to open, edit, and take ownership of the
  selected key, under Permissions for name, for **Full Control**, select
  the Allow check box.
- To grant the user special permission in the selected key, click
  Advanced.

So my question is, would it be possible to do it programmatically? Say, if I want to grant Users **full control** permission on a particular subkey, how should I write the code in C#? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`RegistrySecurity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.registrysecurity.aspx) class is also useful here. So we can write the following code to apply access rules on the registry key for a current user.

```
RegistrySecurity rs = new RegistrySecurity(); // it is right string for this code
string currentUserStr = Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + Environment.UserName;
rs.AddAccessRule(new RegistryAccessRule(currentUserStr, RegistryRights.WriteKey | RegistryRights.ReadKey | RegistryRights.Delete | RegistryRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
```

Comment: For giving permissions to the "everyone" user in a language agnostic way, pass `new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null)` instead of `currentUserStr`.

Answer (score 7):

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key;
key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine;
RegistrySecurity rs = new RegistrySecurity();
rs = key.GetAccessControl();
string currentUserStr = Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + Environment.UserName;
rs.AddAccessRule(
    new RegistryAccessRule(
        currentUserStr, 
        RegistryRights.WriteKey 
        | RegistryRights.ReadKey 
        | RegistryRights.Delete 
        | RegistryRights.FullControl, 
        AccessControlType.Allow));
```

This will assign the access rights to the specified user to the registry key 'key'

Answer (score 1):

It is about `RegSetKeySecurity` API, which is interfaced to from .NET code via `RegistryKey.SetAccessControl`, see [Using RegSetKeySecurity to avoid registry redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851961/using-regsetkeysecurity-to-avoid-registry-redirection)